# How to extract datetime values from a string then adding together

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have a URL with queries where one query key/value is a date time and another key/value is a number of seconds until expiration. I want to extract those values and add them together to get the expiration date time.

Here's an example of the string:

```yaml
s3_objects:
  - item: "path/to/file.txt"
    url: "https://my-bucket.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/path/to/file.txt?X-Amz-Date=20240206T235117Z&X-Amz-Expires=600"
```

There are more queries I didn't include here.

I want to get the `X-Amz-Date` value (`20240206T235117Z`) and add the `X-Amz-Expires` value (`600` seconds). This is what I have so far:

```yaml
s3_object[0].url | urlsplit('query') | split('&') | regex_search('X-Amz-(Date|Expires)=[^&]+')
```

This should give me a list:

```json
[ "X-Amz-Date=20240206T235117Z", "X-Amz-Expires=600" ]
```

I'm not sure where to go from here. To individually split each string then convert from the datetime string and add the seconds, then convert back to a date time.

Ultimately, I want to return an object that looks like this:

```yaml
- file: "path/to/file.txt"
  created: "{{ '%m/%d/%Y %T' | strftime('20240206T235117Z') }}"
  expires: "{{ '%m/%d/%Y %T' | strftime('20240207T000117Z') }}"
  url: "https://my-bucket.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/path/to/file.txt?X-Amz-Date=20240206T235117Z&X-Amz-Expires=600"
```

And this will loop over a list to get a number of the same objects.

Answer (score 1):

I think your first problem is that this...

```
s3_object[0].url | urlsplit('query') | split('&') | regex_search('X-Amz-(Date|Expires)=[^&]+')
```

...does not get you a list. The `regex_search` filter operates on *strings*, while the output from `split('%')` is a *list*, so what you get from the above expression is a mess (it's a stringified version of a Python list data structure).

To get a list, use the `select` filter and the `match` test:

```
s3_object[0].url | urlsplit('query') | split('&') | select('match', 'X-Amz-(Date|Expires)=[^&]+')
```

---

But honestly, I think things start to get hairy if you go down that route. Instead, drop a custom filter into `filter_plugins/filters.py`, something like this:

```
import datetime
from urllib.parse import parse_qs


def extract_s3_times(query, fmt):
    queryvals = parse_qs(query)
    created_at = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(queryvals["X-Amz-Date"][0])
    lifetime = int(queryvals["X-Amz-Expires"][0])
    expires_at = created_at + datetime.timedelta(seconds=lifetime)
    return {
        "created_at": created_at.strftime(fmt),
        "expires_at": expires_at.strftime(fmt),
        "lifetime": lifetime,
    }


class FilterModule:
    def filters(self):
        return {"extract_s3_times": extract_s3_times}
```

Then you can write a playbook like this:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    s3_objects:
      - item: "path/to/file.txt"
        url: "https://my-bucket.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/path/to/file.txt?X-Amz-Date=20240206T235117Z&X-Amz-Expires=600"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg:
          - "file: {{ item.item }}"
          - "created: {{ s3_times.created_at }}"
          - "expires: {{ s3_times.expires_at }}"
          - "url: {{ item.url }}"
      vars:
        s3_times: >
          {{ item.url | urlsplit('query') | extract_s3_times("%m/%d/%Y %T") }}
      loop: "{{ s3_objects }}"
```

Which will produces output like this:

```
TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'item': 'path/to/file.txt', 'url': 'https://my-bucket.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/path/to/file.txt?X-Amz-Date=20240206T235117Z&X-Amz-Expires=600'}) => {
    "msg": [
        "file: path/to/file.txt",
        "created: 02/06/2024 23:51:17",
        "expires: 02/07/2024 00:01:17",
        "url: https://my-bucket.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/path/to/file.txt?X-Amz-Date=20240206T235117Z&X-Amz-Expires=600"
    ]
}
```

Comment: This looks like the way to go. I know next to nothing about python, but it looks like `datetime.datetime.fromisoformat()` is throwing an error: `Invalid isoformat string: '20240207T032419Z'`. I tried [`dateutil.parser.isoparse()`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html#dateutil.parser.isoparse) instead but it's saying there's no 'parser' attribute

Comment: What version of Python are you using? The code presented here works on my system with your sample inputs, using Python 3.11.

Comment: I have python 3.8.13. When I added `from dateutil.parser import isoparse` it worked with just `isoparse()` instead of `datetime.datetime.fromisoformat()`