# How to restructure a list of dicts from a list of dicts?

Tags: ansible

I have a list of S3 object dicts like this:

```yaml
s3_objects:
  - item: "path/to/file.txt"
    url: "https://my-bucket.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/path/to/file.txt?X-Amz-Date=20240206T235117Z&X-Amz-Expires=600"
  - item: "path/to/file2.txt"
    url: "https://my-bucket.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/path/to/file2.txt?X-Amz-Date=20240206T235117Z&X-Amz-Expires=600"
```

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77952024/22146392) I have a custom filter to create the following dict from the URL:

```yaml
- debug:
    var: s3_objects[0].url | urlsplit('query') | extract_s3_times("%m/%d/%Y %T")

# Returns this
{
  "created_at": "02/06/2024 23:51:17",
  "expires_at": "02/07/2024 00:01:17",
  "lifetime": 600
}
```

I'm looking for a way to turn the `s3_objects` list into this list:

```yaml
- file: "path/to/file.txt"
  url: "https://my-bucket.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/path/to/file.txt?X-Amz-Date=20240206T235117Z&X-Amz-Expires=600"
  created: "02/06/2024 23:51:17"
  expires: "02/07/2024 00:01:17"
- file: "path/to/file2.txt"
  url: "https://my-bucket.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/path/to/file2.txt?X-Amz-Date=20240206T235117Z&X-Amz-Expires=600"
  created: "02/06/2024 23:51:17"
  expires: "02/07/2024 00:01:17"
```

I might be able to do it with something like this:

```yaml
- debug:
    msg:
      file: "{{ item.item }}"
      url: "{{ item.url }}"
      created: "{{ s3_times.created_at }}"
      expires: "{{ s3_times.expires_at }}"
    vars:
      s3_times: >
        {{ item.url | urlsplit('query') | extract_s3_times("%m/%d/%Y %T") }}
    loop: "{{ s3_urls.results }}"
    register: new_list

- set_fact:
    new_new_list: "{{ new_list.msg }}"
```

But this seems inefficient and I feel like there's a better way to do it with just a jinja filter.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish what I needed with this:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    new_list: "{{ new_list | default([]) + [{ 'file': item.item, 'url': item.url, 'created': s3_times.created_at, 'expires': s3_times.expires_at }] }}"
  vars:
    s3_times: >
      {{ item.url | urlsplit('query') | extract_s3_times("%m/%d/%Y %T") }}
  with_items: "{{ s3_objects }}"
```